# bash command cat doesn't work inside an if statement

Tags: bash, if-statement, cat

I can create a file with content using a bash script with the `cat` command like so:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

cat >myFyle.txt <<EOL
Some text inside the file
EOL
```

This works as intended. But when I try to use this inside an if statement like so:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

if true; then
    cat >myFyle.txt <<EOL
    Some text inside the file
    EOL
fi
```

I get the error message:

```
Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "fi")
```

Why does this not work and how do I use `cat` correctly inside an if statement?

Note: The condition for the if statement is exemplary. This is just to ensure that the example executes the code.

Comment: The `EOL` needs to start in the first column.  No indent is allowed.  Perhaps try `<<-`

Comment: [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) automatically detects [this](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC1039) and other common problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ending delimiter line has to **exactly** `EOL`. No spaces in front.

```
if true; then
    cat >myFyle.txt <<EOL
    Some text inside the file
EOL
#^^^ Spaces above will be preserved!
fi
```

You can use `<<-EOL` and then use a tab (not spaces!) in front, which will be ignored.

```
if true; then
    cat >myFyle.txt <<-EOL
    Some text inside the file
    EOL
#^^^ - This is a tab. Tabs in front will be ignored.
fi
```

Comment: @LukasFun the text you write will be indented in the file the same amount as in the script, ie in this example you will have 1 tab of indentation at the beginning of every line in myFyle.txt